# Не последовательное отображение элементов FragmentStatePagerAdapter'ом

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть список слов которые должны последовательно выводится на экране при пролистывании. При переходе с MainActivity в FragmentActivity -  метод `public Fragment getItem(int position)` сразу же отрабатывает два раза,  в логи выводится:

- Position: 0 (элемент  списка с индексом 0)
- Position: 1 (элемент списка с индексом 1)

после чего нажав на кнопку NEXT появляется снова элемент списка с индексом 1 (position 2), при этом элемент списка с индексом 0 ни в начале, ни в конце не отображается, все остальные элементы идут по порядку и отображаются правильно!

ИТОГО: элемент списка с индексом 0 - не отображается ни разу, элемент списка с индексом 1 - отображаются два раза, остальные элементы отображаются правильно.

FragmentActivity.java

```
public class LearnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 6;
    private static final String TAG = "LEARN ACTIVITY";

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private Button buttonNext;

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    ArrayList<String> words;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_learn);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            }
        });

        fillArray();

    }

    private void fillArray() {
        words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add(0,"Officia");
        words.add(1,"Lorem ipsum");
        words.add(2,"Minim veniam");
        words.add(3,"Quis nostrud");
        words.add(4,"Exercitation ");
        words.add(5,"Ullamco");

    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Position: " + position);
            return FragmentLearnActivity.create(position, words.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment.java

```
public class FragmentLearnActivity extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

    private int mPageNumber;

    static String word;

    public static FragmentLearnActivity create(int pageNumber,String s) {
        FragmentLearnActivity fragment = new FragmentLearnActivity();
        word = s;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentLearnActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_learn_activity, container, false);

        ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainWord)).setText(word);

        // Set the title view to show the page number.
//        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
//                getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
     */
    public int getPageNumber() {
        return mPageNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что переменная `word` в классе фрагмента - статическая. А значит единое значение имеет для всех экземпляров класса. И т.к. фрагменты для `ViewPager` по умолчанию создаются для 0 и 1 позиции, то этой переменной присваивается значение `words.get(1)`. В дальнейшем, создавая новые фрагменты вы её перезаписываете.

**Решение**

Уберите модификатор `static` у переменной `word` вашего фрагмента. И запихните её значение в `Bundle` вместе с позицией. И так же как последнюю извлекайте в `onCreate`